# NodeJS: Error when I try to execute a command with the scripts of the package.json

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have included the next command in my package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
...
"watch:js": "watch -p ./cartridges/app_skberge_peru/cartridge/client/default/js/*.js  -c npm run compile:js",
...
}
```

When I execute the command in the command line like this:

```
watch -p './cartridges/app_skberge_peru/cartridge/client/default/js/*.js'  -c 'npm run compile:js'
```

It works perfectly but when I try to do it with:

```
npm run watch:js
```

It gives me the next error:

```
> Watching compile:js'
C:\Users\Ángel - Trabajo\Desktop\VISEO\Proyectos\skberge\code\app_skberge_peru\node_modules\watch\main.js:73
    if (err) throw err;
             ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\Ángel - Trabajo\Desktop\VISEO\Proyectos\skberge\code\app_skberge_peru\compile:js''
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app_skberge_peru@0.0.1 watch:js: `watch -p './cartridges/app_skberge_peru/cartridge/client/default/js/*.js'  -c 'npm run compile:js'`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the app_skberge_peru@0.0.1 watch:js script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ángel - Trabajo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-08T17_25_59_377Z-debug.log
```

I'm sure it must be something about formatting inside the quotes but I just can not get what I want.

Thank you !

EDITED:

I tried to execute:

```
"watch:js": "watch -p \"./cartridges/app_skberge_peru/cartridge/client/default/js/*.js\"  -c \"npm run compile:js\""
```

But I receive the next output:

```
> app_skberge_peru@0.0.1 watch:js C:\Users\aquesada\Desktop\Proyectos\skberge\app_skberge_peru
> watch -p "./cartridges/app_skberge_peru/cartridge/client/default/js/*.js"  -c "npm run compile:js"

Usage: watch <command> [...directory] [--wait=<seconds>] [--filter=<file>] [--interval=<seconds>] [--ignoreDotFiles] [--ignoreUnreadable]
```

It's weird because if I execute what you can see in the output in the command line it works perfectly

```
> watch -p "./cartridges/app_skberge_peru/cartridge/client/default/js/*.js"  -c "npm run compile:js"
Watching started
```

Comment: I did! It's so weird, I edited the question with the result.

Comment: Is `watch` an NPM package? Or is it a system-native package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you perhaps install `watch` globally?

If yes, you should install it as a development dependency in your project by `npm i -D watch`. Make sure your current working directory is in your project.

Then, run the script and it should be fine. If that does not work, try adding `npx` to your script, e.g. `npx watch -p <args>`.

That error happens because you installed `watch` as a global dependency. Because of that, when you run it in the command line, it works.